# PHP array_count_values returning an empty array

Tags: php, arrays

Maybe I missed something really obvious but this code doesn't work:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r(($progress)); ?>
<?php print_r(array_count_values ($progress)); ?>
</pre>
```

The output is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 1
)
Array
(
)
```

what is wrong here? why array_count_values returning an empty array?

Comment: Working fine on [codepad](http://codepad.org/YaiIY52y)

Comment: so what can the problem be on my system (php ver. 5.3)?

Comment: Can you show result of `var_export($progress);`?

Comment: Is your error reporting turned on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array_count_values` only works with `string` and `integer` values. My guess: you are storing `booleans` inside `$progress`. You could cast them to `int` before adding them to `$progress`.

Comment: It would raise an error... But if error reporting is off.. this might just be the problem...